# How to open a new window when i click one button?

Tags: javascript

i'm learning javascript and i working with visual studio code and node.js i want to create a logger, when the  button is pressed i need to open a new window i really want to learn how could i do that. I have this code when i press the button and happens nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Fondo-Imagen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="signin">
      <form>
        <h2 style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63)"> Log In</h2>
        <input type="text" name = "rol" placeholder="Rol" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63)">
        <input type="text" name = "username" placeholder="Username" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63)">
        <input type="password" name = "pass" placeholder="Password" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63)"> 
        <br><br>
        <button href=""><input type="button" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63); background-color: 
         white;" value="Log In"></button><br>
        <br>
        <div id="container">
           <a href="#" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63); margin-right:0px; font-size: 13px; 
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">Reset password</a>

        </div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <a href="#" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63)">&nbsp; Sing Up</a>

      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      let button= document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{

       let ref= window.open('new.html','lobby',options);
       });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tons of ways to do this some techniques are here:

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.our-url.com')" id="myButton" class="btn request-callback" >Explore More  </button>
```

You can also do that using anchor tag rather than button because href is not an attribute of button tag like this:

```
<a href="new.html" target="_blank"><input type="button" style="color:rgb(177, 114, 63); background-color:  white;" value="Log In"></a><br>
```

Or you can also do like this:
Try this. This will navigate to the link on click.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'">click me</button>
```

Comment: using an anchor tag was a better idea

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('new.html','_blank');
```

Above code will help you open a blank new tab.

Comment: thanks, that opened a new window  but I get the following message = "cannot Get /new.html"

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a Pop up or a new tab? If you need a pop up you can either use a modal with jquery or with pure create a hidden div in your html and on click remove class hidden with Javascript. If you want to open in a new tab just add `<a href="" target="_blank" > Your Link </a>`

Comment: i think it's better the original tab redirects to another URL